# How to get pre-change Object state from a Class Extension change event in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I have an Esri based system with a class extension registered for the feature classes. This extension implements IObjectClassEvents, and handles OnChange. I get passed the modified object, but *after* the change was made (e.g. an object was moved from within ArcMap).

However, I also need to know the state of the IObject *before* the change was made. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try IFeatureChanges (for features) or more generally, IRowChanges for either a row or a feature.

Comment: Thanks, casting the IObject to IRowChanges gave me exactly what I was looking for.